# Get particular folder from directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a specific sub-folder, such as "b," from the test/foo1 folder in the image below. I'm attempting to do this dynamically so that no hardcoded names appear within the code.  [image]

so what I have achieved till now That I am able to get all the folders inside the
test folder"a,b,c,d", but I dont know how to get any one particular folder dynamically

```
 list=[]
 path =c:test/foo1
subfolders_lst = [f.name for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]
    for subfolder_str in subfolders_lst:
        if subfolder_str in list:
            test_list = [f.name for f in os.scandir(os.path.join(path,subfolder_str)) if f.is_dir()]
```

Comment: Did you try adding `if f.is_dir() and f.name == "b"` anywhere? You will need a hard-coded `b` to search only for that name

Comment: yes, thats what i dont want to hardcod the name like it, it should found dynamically

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "dynamic" then.

Comment: I assume your list will need to contain the 'hard coded' item you wish to match. If you add 'b' to the list, you already have what you need. Within the if condition these are the matching items. I think you're confusing dynamic with magic :P you will need a reference.

Comment: dynamic means without hardcoding the value, I meant to say

Comment: Telling us code runs is not the same as showing us an example that ran and the output of that run.  Example code can not possibly run because `self_test` does not exist, among other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments on the previous answer:

```
import os
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--module', help='Folder Name')
args = parser.parse_args()
folder_name = args.module
look_for = os.path.join('c:\\', 'test', 'foo1', folder_name)
if os.path.isdir(look_for):
  print(f'Found: {look_for}')
else:
  print(f'Did not find {folder_name}')
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer madison, I have tried using it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input()` to not "hard code" a folder to search for, but then you need to provide user-input.

You don't need to scan, either. Just test its existence.

```
import os

folder_name = input('Enter folder name: ')
look_for = os.path.join('c:\\', 'test', 'foo1', folder_name)
if os.path.isdir(look_for):
  print(f'Found: {look_for}')
else:
  print(f'Did not find {folder_name}')
```

Comment: How is this any different from adding it to his list array?

Comment: "Get _one_ folder" does not require a list

Comment: But he has a list and is iterating. I'm guessing getting one folder is an example.

Comment: I am using here a command line like  'python test.py --module= b', so when I will give it , it will print only that b subfolder,

Comment: @Khangesh [use `argparse` to extract your module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Ohk thanks @OneCricketeer I will read this and try to find how to extract it from argparse